# переход на новую строчку UITextField swift4.0

Tags: swift

Создал проект и дoбавил `UITextField`. При наборе не переходит на новую строчку.

Kак сделать?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

UITextField не предназначен для ввода многострочного текста.
Используйте для этих целей [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview)